# Can you do in-place updating/upgrading of Azure VM Operating System?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is there a way to do in-place update the OS of an Azure VM, from within the Azure Portal?
*i.e.* from Windows Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of February 2024, the answer is YES. You can follow the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows-in-place-upgrade article to perform an in-place upgrade of the Operating System of a Virtual Machine running in Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Amazing, after 7 years of asking this 

Answer (score 13):

Nope. As per official article:

> Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of a
>   Microsoft Azure virtual machine. Instead, you should create a new
>   Azure virtual machine that is running the supported version of the
>   operating system that is required and then migrate the workload.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2721672/microsoft-server-software-support-for-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines

Instead, use the Windows Server Migration Tools to assist you in roles and features migration:

[Install, use, and remove Windows Server migration tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj134202)

Comment: This article talks about automatic upgrade of Azure VM .The automatic OS image upgrade feature for Azure scale sets will automatically upgrade all VMs in your scale set to the latest version.https://www.pressreader.com/@Max_Brodin/6786250207940378

Comment: This answer is older, but please note this is incorrect information. As of Feb 2024, the linked article now reads "Microsoft does not support an in-place upgrade of certain versions of the operating system in a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine.". There IS, in fact, a supported in-place upgrade process for Virtual Machines running Windows Servers in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows-in-place-upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by downloading the VHD and doing the upgrade locally with Hyper-V and then reupload it.

More detailed description:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4014997/an-in-place-system-upgrade-is-not-supported-on-windows-based-azure-vms

Comment: This is an older comment, so capabilities have certainly changed. There IS, in fact, a supported in-place upgrade process for Virtual Machines running Windows Servers in Azure that does not involve downloading the VHD and performing an on-prem upgrade within Hyper-V and then re-upload it. Follow the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows-in-place-upgrade article for step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such ability to upgrade an OS on the Azure VM (and not that I heard about it in future, who knows thou).

Comment: There IS, in fact, a supported in-place upgrade process for Virtual Machines running Windows Servers in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows-in-place-upgrade