# Is it possible to change the image running on a virtual machine in Azure without recreating it

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, packer, hotswap

Our development environment has a bunch of virtual machines running different versions of our software. I want to be able to replace the Managed Image that is running on a VM, without having to destroy and recreate it.

The images are created using `packer`, which provisions them with the correct software and dependencies.

##### Example of Current Workflow:

Machine A is running on `Managed Image v2.5`, which runs software with a dependency on `Tomcat 10`.
To fix a bug in `v2.2`, which depends on `Tomcat 9` and thus cannot run on the same VM without changing the dependencies, I have to:

1. Destroy the VM
2. Recreate it using the same arguments (name, size, etc) but based on `Managed Image v2.2`
3. Attach the network interface and disks
4. Restart it

If feel like there should be an easier solution to this, where it is possible to hot-swap the images, without recreating the full virtual machines. I've looked into swapping the OS disk, but I couldn't figure out a solution that would work with Managed Images instead of VHD's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per official article, its not Supported.

> Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of a
> Microsoft Azure virtual machine. Instead, you should create a new
> Azure virtual machine that is running the supported version of the
> operating system that is required and then migrate the workload.

Official article : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2721672/microsoft-server-software-support-for-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines

Instead you can use windows server migration tool that would assist you in roles and feature's migration
[Install, use, and remove Windows Server migration tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj134202)

Similar issue discussed at [Can you do in-place updating/upgrading of Azure VM Operating System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923827/can-you-do-in-place-updating-upgrading-of-azure-vm-operating-system)